# Open files from Linux bash shell on Windows 10

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using Windows 10 and I have the Linux Bash Shell to use with Jekyll.

All I am looking to do is open the explorer or filesystem to copy some files. Does anyone know how you browse the file explorer with the shell or achieve what I want in another way?

I am looking to open a path which lives on

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-2.5.0
```

Essentially I want to do the Linux Bash Shell (Windows 10) equivalent of

```
explorer /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-2.5.0
```

I installed nautilus

```
str@DESKTOP-SMMADM5:/mnt/c/WorkingProjects/personal$ sudo apt install nautilus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  adwaita-icon-theme at-spi2-core colord colord-data dbus-x11 dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service desktop-file-utils
  fontconfig gcr glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnome-desktop3-data gnome-keyring
  gsettings-desktop-schemas gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-libs hicolor-icon-theme
  humanity-icon-theme hwdata libarchive13 libassuan0 libatasmart4 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data
  libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-glib1 libboost-filesystem1.58.0
  libboost-system1.58.0 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcapnp-0.5.3 libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13
  libcolord2 libcolorhug2 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdconf1 libdee-1.0-4 libegl1-mesa libepoxy0
  libexempi3 libexif12 libgail-3-0 libgbm1 libgck-1-0 libgcr-3-common libgcr-base-3-1 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgd3
  libgdata-common libgdata22 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgnome-desktop-3-12 libgoa-1.0-0b
  libgoa-1.0-common libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port12 libgraphite2-3 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtk-3-common libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2 libharfbuzz0b libieee1284-3 libimobiledevice6 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8
  libjpeg8 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common liblcms2-2 libldb1 libmediaart-2.0-0 libmirclient9 libmircommon7
  libmircore1 libmirprotobuf3 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libnautilus-extension1a libnotify4 libnspr4 libnss3
  libnss3-nssdb liboauth0 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libpam-gnome-keyring libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0
  libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpixman-1-0 libplist3 libprotobuf-lite9v5 libproxy1v5 libpython2.7 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2
  librsvg2-common libsane libsane-common libsecret-1-0 libsecret-common libsmbclient libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1
  libtalloc2 libtdb1 libtevent0 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libtracker-sparql-1.0-0 libudisks2-0
  libunity-protocol-private0 libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop libunity9 libusbmuxd4 libvpx3 libwayland-client0
  libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1-mesa libwayland-server0 libwbclient0 libxapian22v5 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0
  libxcb-xfixes0 libxkbcommon0 libzeitgeist-2.0-0 nautilus-data notification-daemon p11-kit p11-kit-modules
  pinentry-gnome3 python-talloc samba-libs session-migration ubuntu-mono udisks2 usbmuxd zeitgeist-core
Suggested packages:
  colord-sensor-argyll bluez-obexd samba-common lrzip cups-common libgd-tools gphoto2 libusbmuxd-tools liblcms2-utils
  librsvg2-bin avahi-daemon hplip libsane-extras sane-utils unity-common xapian-tools brasero eog evince | pdf-viewer
  totem | mp3-decoder tracker gnome-sushi pinentry-doc reiserfsprogs exfat-utils zeitgeist-datahub
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  adwaita-icon-theme at-spi2-core colord colord-data dbus-x11 dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service desktop-file-utils
  fontconfig gcr glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnome-desktop3-data gnome-keyring
  gsettings-desktop-schemas gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-libs hicolor-icon-theme
  humanity-icon-theme hwdata libarchive13 libassuan0 libatasmart4 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data
  libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-glib1 libboost-filesystem1.58.0
  libboost-system1.58.0 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcapnp-0.5.3 libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13
  libcolord2 libcolorhug2 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdconf1 libdee-1.0-4 libegl1-mesa libepoxy0
  libexempi3 libexif12 libgail-3-0 libgbm1 libgck-1-0 libgcr-3-common libgcr-base-3-1 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgd3
Setting up libgoa-1.0-0b:amd64 (3.18.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libnspr4:amd64 (2:4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libgdata-common (0.17.4-1) ...
Setting up libplist3:amd64 (1.12-3.1ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libusbmuxd4:amd64 (1.0.10-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libimobiledevice6:amd64 (1.2.0+dfsg-3~ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up hwdata (0.267-1) ...
Setting up libdbusmenu-glib4:amd64 (16.04.1+16.04.20160927-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgphoto2-l10n (2.5.9-3) ...
Setting up libmediaart-2.0-0:amd64 (1.9.0-2) ...
Setting up libmtp-runtime (1.1.10-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libtracker-sparql-1.0-0:amd64 (1.6.2-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libunity-protocol-private0:amd64 (7.1.4+16.04.20180209.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop (7.1.4+16.04.20180209.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libunity9:amd64 (7.1.4+16.04.20180209.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up session-migration (0.2.3) ...
Setting up nautilus-data (1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu6) ...
Setting up usbmuxd (1.1.0-2) ...
Warning: The home dir /var/lib/usbmux you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory
Adding system user `usbmux' (UID 113) ...
Adding new user `usbmux' (UID 113) with group `plugdev' ...
Not creating home directory `/var/lib/usbmux'.
Setting up libgtk-3-bin (3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Setting up adwaita-icon-theme (3.18.0-2ubuntu3.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursor.theme to provide /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme (x-curs
or-theme) in auto mode
Setting up humanity-icon-theme (0.6.10.1) ...
Setting up libnss3-nssdb (2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Setting up libnss3:amd64 (2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Setting up liboauth0:amd64 (1.0.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libgdata22:amd64 (0.17.4-1) ...
Setting up ubuntu-mono (14.04+16.04.20180326-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgtk-3-common (3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Setting up libgtk-3-0:amd64 (3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Setting up libgcr-ui-3-1:amd64 (3.18.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gcr (3.18.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up pinentry-gnome3 (0.9.7-3) ...
Setting up gnome-keyring (3.18.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up gvfs-backends (1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2) ...
Setting up libgail-3-0:amd64 (3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Setting up libgnome-desktop-3-12:amd64 (3.18.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libnautilus-extension1a:amd64 (1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu6) ...
Setting up nautilus (1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu6) ...
Setting up notification-daemon (3.18.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.4) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
```

But when I try and open the path I get

```
str@DESKTOP-SMMADM5:/mnt/c/WorkingProjects/personal$ nautilus /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-2.5.0
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(nautilus:6622): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

EDIT :

Installed xdg-utils (Thanks Brydon) which did not work and gave the following output here

```
stradled@DESKTOP-SMMADM5:/mnt/c/WorkingProjects/personal$ xdg-open /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-2.5.0
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /usr/bin/run-mailcap line 528.
Error: no "view" mailcap rules found for type "inode/directory"
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening '/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-2.5.0'
```

Comment: Pretty sure that bash on windows does not have a display server at all, so you can't launch GUI applications.

Comment: As glenn said, this is impossible to run GUI apps in wsl out of the box. You'll have to install a 3rd party X server like VcxSrv and bind it to your wsl install. Note that there are still some caveats with this solution

Comment: [Here's a tutorial on how to do that](https://www.howtogeek.com/261575/how-to-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/)

Answer (score 1):

No need for anything fancy like suggested in other answers, wsl and windows has great support for opening windows files and apps from within WSL and visa versa.

Firstly remember you should not open and mess with linux files from windows ([link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)). But for windows files and folders (for example: \mnt\c...) you can open these with `start .`

For this to work you will need an alias in your linux env set like this

```
alias start='cmd.exe /c start'
```

If do want to manipulate files in the linux filesystem you could use a dual pane console file manager like [midnight commander](https://midnight-commander.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Hashicorp Vault in WSL.

I created a script that basically forwards `xdg-open` to `powershell -c start`

Not tested much though.

```sh
sudo tee /usr/local/bin/xdg-open <<EOF
#!/bin/sh

powershell.exe -c start "'\$@'"
EOF
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/xdg-open
```

Then `xdg-open https://google.com` should work.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I didn't realize this was on WSL, this will not work unless there is a display server

xdg-open does seem to work on a directory (if you don't know what your default file explorer is).

```
xdg-open /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-2.5.0
```

The only input I have in the nautilus issue is to ensure that you're spelling it correctly and the install is actually working (not throwing an error). Read carefully through the output of `apt-get install nautilus` or post it here.

Comment: Updated question with bit more info, let me know if you want anything else